# AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'q'

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to append a simple string to a list in and object. But I'm guessing the self keyword is interfereing with the pyqt window?

How can I work around this?

```
class Window(qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.CreateWidgets()       
        self.q = Qfetch.DataFetch()

    def CreateWidgets(self):
        toPortfolio = "str"
        self.q.Portfolio.append(toPortfolio) #<---- This cause the error
```

q class

```
class DataFetch():
    def __init__(self):
        self.Portfolio = []
```

Comment: Just for clarification, is CreateWidgets a function member of the Window class? If it is, it should be indented one notch inside the Window class.

Comment: @FilipHedman Yes it is. I fixed it now. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to fetch the member **q** before it is initialized. Call Qfetch.DataFetch() before self.CreateWidgets().

This code for the constructor should work:

```
class Window(qt.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.q = Qfetch.DataFetch()
        self.CreateWidgets()
```

Comment: How embarrasing. Thank you!